# How to configure php-flasher dependencies with Laravel 10 without getting the error "Flasher is not loaded"

Tags: laravel-10

//composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^10.0
         ...
        "php-flasher/flasher-laravel": "^1.13",
        "php-flasher/flasher-sweetalert-laravel": "^1.13",
        "php-flasher/flasher-toastr-laravel": "^1.13",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.25",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.0"
    },
    ...
```

// Component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Flasher\Toastr\Laravel\Facade\Toastr;

public function someFunction() {
  Toastr::livewire()->addSuccess("Language settings saved");
}
```

// error message

```
Flasher is not loaded
```

This is the error message in the console when somefunction is called.

I upgraded from Laravel 8 to Laravel 10 and was required to update the libraries to a supported version with previous versions being:

```
        "php-flasher/flasher-livewire": "^0.9.6",
        "php-flasher/flasher-sweet-alert-laravel": "^0.9.6",
        "php-flasher/flasher-toastr-laravel": "^0.9.5",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.25",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~5.0"
```